# Mobile Connect Reporting - Hidden data vidws for device type / operating system

Tags: marketing-cloud, marketing-cloud-connect, mobileconnect

I am trying to understand what mobile devices our customers have (Smart Phone vs Non Smart phone) so wanted to know if there are any hidden data view fields that store this information around the device type/operating system that a SMS Push message has been set to? In other tools I have used in the past this was available however it doesn't look like Marketing Cloud Mobile Connect has this information. Or is their a way to capture this via AMPScript or any recommendations other than surveying our customers?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Assuming `SMS Push message` is a SMS message sent through mobile connect and the carriers.

Mobile connect does not capture any device data, nor would I even imagine how other platforms would collect this data sending SMS

If you mean Mobile PUSH, there are device details sent through the SDK and registration payload you could leverage within mobile filtered lists